# Check condition on diagonal entries of matrix in Julia?

Tags: arrays, loops, matrix, julia, numerical-methods

In Julia, suppose I have a matrix A, and I would like to know the number of diagonal entries that are smaller than some threshold value. One way to do this is to initialize a new array of diagonal entries of A with **diag()**, and  then use the **count** function to count how many are below some threshold value.

```
A_diag=(diag(A))
count(<(0.1), A_diag)
```

But, I prefer ***not to initialize any new arrays*** (as I did with the diag function). Is there any way in Julia to check how many diagonal entries of a matrix satisfy some condition, without initializing any **NEW** arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this count quite fast without creating a new array for diagonal elements by working directly on the given matrix. Using a generator instead of `diag(A)` will by 3X faster.

```
count(<(0.1), A[i,i] for i in minimum(axes(A)))
```

Comparing the speed of the following variants in Julia 1.9.0-DEV shows a speed advantage of my solution.

```
A = rand(500,500)
@btime count(<(0.1), diag($A))
@btime count(<(0.1), $A[i] for i in diagind($A))
@btime count(<(0.1), $A[i,i] for i in minimum(axes($A)))
  # 697.931 ns (1 allocation: 4.06 KiB)
  # 495.876 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
  # 213.962 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

In Julia 1.8.0, however, the numbers are more close:

```
  # 668.387 ns (1 allocation: 4.06 KiB)
  # 345.370 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
  # 317.373 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: Or `count(<(0.1), A[i] for i in diagind(A))`

Comment: Sure it does the same thing, but is going to be much slower.

Comment: Just as fast (or a decent bit faster on small matrices) for me - guess it could be platform dependent

Comment: `diagind` is the way to go. It is lazy, like `axes` or `eachindex`.

Comment: @DNF I added some benchmarks, it seems like `diagind` is not as fast as `axes` on my end. I'm not sure if this can be replicated on the machines of other people.

Comment: On my laptop `diagind` is faster for small matrices, then converge to similar speed for larger ones. Another thing is that I'm not sure what to think of `minimum(axes(A))`. It works, but it's weird. Is `1:4` less than `1:5`? Yes, apparently. But also `0:10` is less than `1:3`. This may not impact actual matrices, but it's a bit unsettling.

Comment: Maybe tidier to write `count(A[i] < 0 for i in diagind(A))`. It looks like the `diagind` version fails to automatically remove bounds checks, `count(@inbounds(A[i]<0.1) for i in diagind(A))` is faster, but adding this annotation to the `A[i,i]` version has no effect.